# Theorem of Galvin, Mycielski and Solovay

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I don't know is this the right place to ask this question, but can someone tell me where I can find the proof of the theorem of Galvin, Mycielski and Solovay. Theorem that says that a subset $X$ of real line has strong measure zero if, and only if, for each first category set $M$, the set $X+M$ is not the entire real line.

Comment: Did you look in Did you look in Bartoszynski/Judah's [**Set Theory: On the Structure of the Real Line**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/156881044X)? This is where I would first look, but my copy is at home and I'm not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galvin–Mycielski–Solovay theorem is Theorem 3.5 of ["Special subsets of the real line"](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/special.pdf) by Arnold W. Miller, which is Chapter 5 of the *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*; the proof is on pp. 209–210.

**P.S.** As suggested in a comment by Dave L. Renfro, that theorem can also be found in the book *Set Theory: On the Structure of the Real Line* by Tomek Bartoszyński and Haim Judah; it's Theorem 8.1.16 on p. 405, and the proof is on pp 405–406.

**P.P.S.** Another proof can be found in the paper:

[Fred Galvin, Jan Mycielski, and Robert M. Solovay, "Strong measure zero and infinite games", *Arch. Math. Logic* 56 (2017), 725–732](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-017-0541-z).

A version of that paper is available for free on [Arnold W. Miller's website](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m873-14/GalvinMycielskiSolovay.pdf).